# php compare two multidimensional array and check for duplicate

Tags: php

I have two arrays

```
$array1 = array(
    0 => array(
        'user' => 'user0',
        'id' => 'id0'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'user' => 'user1',
        'id' => 'id1'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'user' => 'user2',
        'id' => 'id2'
    )
);

$array2 = array(
    0 => array(
        'emp' => 'emp0',
        'id' => 'id3'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'emp' => 'emp1',
        'id' => 'id1'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'emp' => 'emp2',
        'id' => 'id2'
    )
);
```

i need to loop array 2 first an d give input of id from array1 to the array 1 and search whether the value of id1 from arr1 exists in array2

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. You mentioned: "... loop array 2 first and give input of id from array1 to the array1". Can you please try to write an example of a required output?

Comment: Do you mean to search through both arrays with given id? For instance for id => 'id1' it would produce array with 2 elements containing user information and employment information?

Comment: Please review my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work? (If I understood your question correctly)

```
$id_arr = array();
$final_arr = array();

checkArray($array1, $id_arr, $final_arr);
checkArray($array2, $id_arr, $final_arr);

function checkArray($arr, &$id_arr, &$final_arr) {
  foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($value['id'], $id_arr)) {
      $id_arr[] = $value['id'];
      $final_arr[] = $value;
    }
  }
}

var_dump($final_arr);
```

Comment: No this is not the op i require,actually i modifed the question here

Comment: Please write an example of an output array so that I'm able to help you.